# IBM Cloud Private Installation: etcd not starting

Tags: etcd, ibm-cloud-private

I have been following this guide https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_2.1.0/installing/install_containers_CE.html to install ICP in 2 nodes. 
While everything is going well I get the following error:

```
TASK [master : Waiting for Etcd to start] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "elapsed": 600, "failed": true, "msg": "The Etcd component failed to start. For more details, see https://ibm.biz/etcd-fails."}
```

I can confirm that there are no firewall issues in the ports.
I tried running the installation using -vvv flag but still not clear what the issue could be.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the configuration whether it is properly made using the following steps as described in this [Github](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/master/Documentation/reporting_bugs.md)
Sometimes cloud-config might be wrong!
If this did not help you can try this one: 
https://github.com/coreos/etcd/issues/4308

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I solved it with help of this thread https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/54542.

You just need to turn swap off with "swapoff -a".